# Efficiently Following the Links in a Directed Graph (Common Lisp)

Tags: common-lisp, symbols

I’d like to develop an efficient strategy that can quickly test if a pre-specified path exists in a large fully-connected directed labeled graph.  For example, starting at some node, say node0, does there exist a path to another node, say node9, that follows a sequence of labeled links, say node0 -> link3 -> link1 -> link4+ -> link1 -> node9, where link+ means one or more repetitions of that link’s label.  The graph is dynamic, such that nodes and links will be continuously added and deleted.  Unique node and link labels would be strings constructed from underlying semantic information.

My first (simplest) idea is to intern all labeled graph nodes and links in a separate package as symbols.  Then install a hash table as the symbol-value of each node.  The hash table would carry the associations for that node from all of the links emanating from that node to their respective target nodes.  Testing whether the next link in the chain exists, then is a simple table lookup.  The total number of lookups depends on the length of the chain of links.  All programmatic references to node and label symbols would be via the package name.

However, I’m not sure about the advisability of using symbols and symbol values as data structures.  Does putting them in their own package mitigate potential conflicts in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use symbols, you do not need hash-tables; you can store data in the `symbol-value` slot of the symbol, and any additional data in its `symbol-plist`. Lookup is either already done at read time, or with `find-symbol` or `intern` at runtime. You could use `unintern` to dissociate the symbol from its home package, but other nodes could still reference it, so you would need to remove any other reference to that symbol when removing a node (that's why sometimes you store both the ingoing and outgoing edges of a node).

It can be done, and as far as I know, this used to be a common way to work with symbols historically. One possible drawback is that when you create a package you have to name it (so no on-the-fly, anonymous package). You have to potentially choose a string that is not currently used as a package name, and you restrict the name of your nodes to a specific package.

Another way to implement this is to have a `node` class which holds a `name`, where the name can be any symbol the user choose (in any package). A `graph` class maintains all nodes, and edges, etc, and you can manipulate those objects in isolation, without messing up with the environment's list of packages, etc. This could be a little bit cleaner.

It was recently made available, so I'd like also to point out that this book exists: [Programming Algorithms](https://leanpub.com/progalgs/read) by Vsevolod Domkin, which uses Common Lisp to implement algorithms.

Comment: Well, it looks like there’s not much difference in using symbols vs class/structure instances for nodes. Lookup using symbols `(gethash link node)` vs using node instances `(gethash link (node-links node))`. So instances should be cleaner, as you note, even with the added indirection. But how can the symbol approach avoid a hash table for each node to hold the node’s outgoing links to the next node?  That would be a big advantage. Looking forward to `Programming Algorithms`.

Comment: for example `(get symbol 'succ-nodes)` => list of successor nodes

Comment: Yes, but determining which successor node is next depends on the link label. Still seems to require a hash table for each symbol, in this case on its property list.

Comment: @davypough yes, if you need to find links by name the property list could hold a hash-table

Answer (score 0):

Rather than obsess about implementation, I would design a *protocol* which the system needs to follow.  Here is one such (note I have made some assumptions here, some of which are probably implicit, and none of which may agree with how you want things to work):

```
;;;; Protocol
;;;
;;; By assumption there is one link with each label, each link points
;;; at one other node.
;;;
;;; NODEs have identity and can be destructively modified but it is
;;; not specified whether node equality is object identity.
;;;

(defgeneric node-link-labelled (node label)
  (:documentation "Return the node linked to NODE via LABEL, or NIL".))

(defgeneric (setf node-link-labelled) (target node label)
  (:documentation "set the link with label LABEL of NODE to TARGET, replacing it if
it exists.  Return TARGET."))

(defgeneric nodes-equal (n1 n2)
  (:documentation "Are N1 and N2 the same node?"))

(defgeneric node-remove-link (node label)
  (:documentation "Remove the link with label LABEL from NODE.  Return NODE.

The link need not exist"))

(defgeneric mapc-node-links (fn node)
  (:documentation "call FN with arguments NODE, LABEL TARGET for each link of NODE.

FN is allowed to delete the link corresponding to LABEL but should not otherwise
modify NODE"))
```

Then you can write implementations for this protocol.  Here is a simple one in which nodes are conses of `(<something> . <links>)`.  This will be slow for large numbers of links, but probably very fast for small numbers.  It has the nice feature that you can give nodes names, which is not supported in the above protocol.

```
;;;; Consy nodes are simple
;;;

(defun make-consy-node (&optional (label 'node))
  (list label))

(defmethod node-link-labelled ((node cons) label)
  (cdr (assoc label (cdr node))))

(defmethod nodes-equal ((n1 cons) (n2 cons))
  (eql n1 n2))

(defmethod (setf node-link-labelled) (target (node cons) label)
  (let ((found (assoc label (cdr node))))
    (if found
        (setf (cdr found) target)
      (push (cons label target) (cdr node))))
  target)

(defmethod node-remove-link ((node cons) label)
  (setf (cdr node) (delete-if (lambda (link)
                                (eql (car link) label))
                              (cdr node)))
  node)

(defmethod mapc-node-links (fn (node cons))
  ;; This is at least safe
  (loop for (label . target) in (copy-list (cdr node))
        do (funcall fn node label target))
  node)
```

Or you can implement nodes as hash tables, which will be fast for graphs with many per-node links:

```
;;;; Hashy nodes
;;;

(defun make-hashy-node ()
  (make-hash-table))

(defmethod nodes-equal ((n1 hash-table) (n2 hash-table))
  (eql n1 n2))

(defmethod node-link-labelled ((node hash-table) label)
  (values (gethash label node nil)))

(defmethod (setf node-link-labelled) (target (node hash-table) label)
  (setf (gethash label node) target)
  target)

(defmethod node-remove-link ((node hash-table) label)
  (remhash label node)
  node)

(defmethod mapc-node-links (fn (node hash-table))
  (maphash (lambda (label target)
             (funcall fn node label target))
           node)
  node)
```

Or you can do any number of other things.  And since they all follow the protocol you can mix them:

```
(let ((n1 (make-hashy-node)))
  (setf (node-link-labelled n1 'foo) (make-hashy-node)
        (node-link-labelled n1 'bar) (make-consy-node 'n2))
  n1)
```

You can define node construction as part of the protocol if you want:

```
(defgeneric make-node-of-sort (sort &key)
  (:documentation "make a node whose sort is SORT.  Methods on this GF should
use EQL specializers on SORT"))

...

(defmethod make-node-of-sort ((sort (eql 'consy)) &key (name 'node))
  (list name))

...
```

Comment: Thanks for the protocol jump-start.  I should be able to adapt this interface more or less directly.